# trying to catch error with Add-QADGroupMember

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I'm writing a script to bulk add users from a CSV, then add groups from another user.

It's working fine, except that some groups i'm not able to add (I get access denied when using the AD MMC - we have to get a different group to add them for us).  The problem is that Add-QADGroupMember silently fails.  I would like to somehow catch the error and list the groups that I have to get added by the different group.

I've tried try/catch, but it doesn't work... i'm at a loss.

Here is the code at the moment:

```
$users = Import-Csv .\UserList.csv

foreach ($user in $users) {
$SameAs = $user.SameAs
$UserGroups = (Get-QADUser $SameAs).MemberOf
foreach ($group in $UserGroups) {
Add-QADGroupMember $group -Member $user.SamAccountName |Out-Null
}
}
```

I'm just not able to get it to throw an error or exception when it fails to add a group.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the erroraction to "stop".

I had the same problem with PowerCLI and all commands from there.

Try it so:

```
Add-QADGroupMember $group -Member $user.SamAccountName -ErrorAction Stop |Out-Null
```

or you can set the ErrorActionPreference global with

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
```