# Creating a PS query for get-adcomputer

Tags: powershell

I Am trying to get a csv of computers that are in a security group "Security Group A" and then filter based on LastlogonTimestamp so that any computers that haven't logged on for 60 days will not be in the result. I have tried a few different ways but i am not having any luck.
I was wondering if anybody can assist.
Currently I have tried

```
`$lastlogon = (get-date).adddays(-60).ToFileTime()

Get-ADGroupmember "Security Group A" | Select Name
```

I am not sure how I can pipe this out from here. I have tried using a variable of $comp but i get an error about not being an ad object but rather a system object.

The other option is

```
$lastlogon = (get-date).adddays(-60).ToFileTime()
Get-ADGroup "Security Group A" -properties members | %{$_.members} | %{get-adcomputer $_ |select name | out-file C:\temp\output.csv
```

With the last one i have tried to add

```
-filter {Lastlogontimestamp -gt $lastlogon}
```

after the $_ and before but that seems to return an empty CSV (i know there are results).

I am doing something wrong...any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: does my answer works ? @JohnyV

Comment: Sorry @Solaflex i have not tried yet. I will try today and update. Thanks though.

Comment: Didnt work for me. Query didnt produce any errors however it didnt output anything either.

Comment: if you have problems with exceptions or just "No exception", take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271552/trying-to-catch-error-with-add-qadgroupmember/16271987#16271987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
[DateTime]$lastlogon = (get-date).adddays(-60).ToFileTime()

$Computers = Get-ADGroupmember "Security Group A" | Select-Object Name,@{Name="Stamp"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}}

$Computers | where {$_.lastLogonTimestamp -gt $lastlogon} | select name | out-file C:\temp\output.csv -Force
```

Tested with a Distribution Group, but should also work in a security group

Comment: This worked though     [long]$lastlogon = (get-date).adddays(-60).ToFileTime() Get-ADGroupMember “Security Group A” | %{Get-ADComputer $_ -Properties lastlogontimestamp| where {$_.lastlogontimestamp -gt $lastlogon} | select name } |export-csv c:\temp\output.csv

Comment: perfect :)
See you in the next question ;)